# What is the probability that no wife will be on the same team as her husband? that exactly $k$ teams are composed of married couples?

Tags: probability, permutations

$N$ teams of $2$ people are composed by choosing randomly $1$ man and $1$ woman from $N$ married couples.

1. Calculate the probability that no wife will be on the same team as her husband.
2. Calculate the probability that exactly $k$ teams are composed of married couples.

I was thinking in this way:

Husbands are the indexes of a vector (`numbers`) and the women are the values of the vector (`characters`).
So, we've the following situation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & ... & N\\ 
A_1 & A_2 & A_3 & ... & A_N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So, we need Permutation of `N` objects in `N` positions to define $\Omega$:
$$
\Omega = N!
$$

From now on, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you familiar with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)?

Comment: No, I didn't know what derangements are. This can answer the point **1**. What about the point **2**? Should I start from `i=k` and finish to `n=N` or shoud I start from `i=1` and finish to `n=k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $!m$ denote the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $m$ objects.

Answer on 1) is:$$!N\times\frac1{N!}$$

Answer on 2) is $$\binom{N}{k}\times!(N-k)\times\frac1{N!}$$ The first factor is the number of possibilities by choosing $k$ of the $N$ men to be reunited with their wives.

The second factor is the number of ways to couple the remaining women with a man that is not their husband.